# Unable to run Postgres after Installation on OSX - El Capitan

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew, postgresql-9.5

I just used homebrew to install my postgres, and I am unable to start it after attempting to start it with the suggested command from postgres/brew.

[image]

Can someone please advise?

Comment: Did you run initdb? BTW could you copy paste the text from the terminal next time instead of making a screen shot, is more readable and searchable.

Comment: @Eelke Thank you very much - this helped. I did run initdb.

Comment: Then it probably did fail for some reason. Make sure the folder is empty and try rerunning initdb. The command should probably be at least `initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgresql -E utf8` (you may wish to suplly additional arguments). If it fails or you are not sure it succeeded post both the command line you used and the output in your question.